# Mac fails to boot up after crash, showing white lines, disk checks out OK

Tags: macos, startup, single-user, safe-mode

I'm running an old Mac Pro (early 2009) with Lion 10.7, 650GB hard drive near full. This morning the computer became unresponsive besides the mouse and showed columns of light gray lines across the screen. I rebooted and since then the Mac will show a kernel panic on the gray screen after the spinning for several seconds.

Troubleshooting:

- Safe Boot fails, it hangs at 20% progress bar
- I reset the PRAM a couple times, no change
- Recovery mode (option key) shows my drive and the recovery drive, but the recovery drive doesn't boot up either. The spinner will eventually freeze with both regular boot and Safe Boot
- Pulled power cable for SMC reset, no change
- Target Disk mode seems to work (Firewire icon shows) but I can't connect with it via Ethernet and I don't have the cable to connect it with any of my other Macs
- Verbose mode output is shown in image below, it hangs at this point
- Single User mode seems to work OK. fsck reports my main HD is OK and I was able to enable diskutil and verify it there too. While I was in I deleted about 10GB of data (rm -rf) hoping it just needs more disk space to boot, but I see no change.

I'm to the point where I suspect a graphics hardware issue, needing to do something so the HD can reclaim the emptied space, or Firefox left some corrupted tmp file or something. That's the one app I had running at the time.

[image]

Comment: I would bet that your GPU just took a dive.  The fact that you can get into SU mode (text) and not into anything with a GUI confirms this.  Your data should be intact and you can pull it off via SU or Target Disk Mode.  If you can get a GPU card cheap, it might be worth it to fix this machine.  The Mac Pros were (and still are) a good, stable platform.

Comment: I concur with Allan. I fixed my friend's Mac Pro by replacing the GPU card. This [handy page at Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201805) shows you manufacturers and models of GPU cards applicable to your model of Mac Pro (which you don't mention.)

Comment: @IconDaemon, thanks, I've amended my post. My model is early 2009.

Comment: Before you go on a (possibly futile) search for a working GPU card, open the case, and if you are comfortable doing so, reseat the GPU card in its slot. I worked on a succession of Mac Pros for my friend who could only use ancient music production & editing software which ran under Snow Leopard, IIRC. A lot of intermittent problems disappeared with a simple reseating of the PCIe audio cards, the GPU cards and RAM. **!! Protect the Mac from antistatic shock !!**. You have been warned. :-)

Comment: just to note, the HD 5770 will also work in an 08 or 09; that's what we have in all the old Mac Pros here. I'd also think it would be worthwhile to change the PRAM battery, for the sake of a buck. Much random weirdness occurs if they go flat.

Comment: I reseated the card (NVIDIA Quadro 4000) and cleaned out the dust, but the issue wasn't resolved. Rather than buy a new card or Firewire adapter, I connected an external drive and I'm copying the internal drives to that with cp, but might eventually get some docking stations to connect them to the new computer. Thanks!